# Properly aligned entries of a matrix using nicematrix

Tags: matrices, nicematrix

I have written two matrices, using `pNiceMatrix` package and using `pmatrix`. However, I am facing difficulties in getting them aligned properly, especially when negative entries are present in the matrices.

The first one, when I write using `pmatrix` is something like this

```
\begin{equation}
A =\begin{pmatrix}
\p 1 & \p 0 & \p\cdots & \p\cdots & \p 0 \\
-1 & \p 1 & \p 0 & \p\cdots & \p 0\\
\p 0 & -1 &\p \ddots & \p \ddots & \p\vdots\\
\p \vdots & \p 0 & \p\ddots & \p\ddots & \p 0\\
\p \vdots & \p \vdots & \p\ddots & \p\ddots & \p 1\\
\p 0 & \p 0 & \p\cdots & \p 0 & -1
\end{pmatrix},
\end{equation}
```

where `\p` is representative of `\newcommand{\p}{\phantom{-}}`. The output is something like this.

[image]

The same matrix, when written as

```
\begin{equation}
A =\begin{pNiceMatrix}
 1      &  0      &  \Cdots &       &  0        \\
-1      &  \Ddots &  \Ddots &       &  \Vdots   \\
 0      & \Ddots  &         &       &           \\
 \Vdots &  \Ddots &         &       &  0        \\
        &         &         &       &  1        \\
 0      & \Cdots  &         &  0    & -1
\end{pNiceMatrix},
\end{equation}
```

results in a rather misaligned one.

[image]

How do I correct such misalignment? This really seems to create issues when I write long matrices, such as

```
\begin{equation}
    \begin{pmatrix}
        B = w_{\ell,\ell+1}+w_{\ell,\ell-1} & -w_{\ell,\ell+1} &  0 &  \cdots & 0 & -w_{\ell,\ell-1} \\
        -w_{\ell,\ell-1} & \ddots & \ddots &  \ddots & \ddots & 0  \\
        0 & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots &  \ddots &  \vdots  \\
        \vdots & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots &  \ddots  &  0\\
        0 & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots & -w_{\ell,\ell-1} \\ 
        -w_{\ell,\ell+1} & 0 & \cdots & 0 & -w_{\ell,\ell-1} & w_{\ell,\ell+1}+w_{\ell,\ell-1}
    \end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may use the option `r` of `{NiceMatrix}`. I have added `nullify-dots` to have all the lines with the same height.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
A =\begin{pNiceMatrix}[r,nullify-dots]
 1      &  0      &  \Cdots &       &  0        \\
-1      &  \Ddots &  \Ddots &       &  \Vdots   \\
 0      & \Ddots  &         &       &           \\
 \Vdots &  \Ddots &         &       &  0        \\
        &         &         &       &  1        \\
 0      & \Cdots  &         &  0    & -1
\end{pNiceMatrix}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image: Result of above code]

Comment: Thanks for the info. Let me try for large matrices too.

Answer (score 3):

If you add `nullify dots`, it looks much better IMHO.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
A =\begin{pNiceMatrix}[nullify-dots]
 1      &  0      &  \Cdots &       &  0        \\
-1      &  \Ddots &  \Ddots &       &  \Vdots   \\
 0      & \Ddots  &         &       &           \\
 \Vdots &  \Ddots &         &       &  0        \\
        &         &         &       &  1        \\
 0      & \Cdots  &         &  0    & -1
\end{pNiceMatrix},
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the info. Let me try for large matrices too.